# Displacement current density in capacitors

Tags: electromagnetism

I have the following problem from electrodynamics by Griffiths.

In problem 34:

> A fat wire, radius a, carries a constant current I, uniformly distributed over its cross-section. A narrow gap in the wire of width $w\ll a$, forms a parallel plate capacitor.
> Find the magnetic field in the gap, at a distance s<a from the axis.

The diagram is the following:

> [image: Blockquote]

To find the magnetic field we have used Maxwell-Ampere's Law and Amperian loop.

The equation is as follows: $$ \int B \cdot dl =\mu_0\int (J\cdot da)+\mu_0\int (J_\text{displacement} \cdot da)$$

In all of the solutions I have seen, they have $\int (J\cdot da)=0$.

Can anyone explain what the enclosed current would be zero.

Comment: Why would you think the enclosed displacement current is zero? Obviously the enclosed conduction current is zero, because there isn't a conduction current in the gap